# Как менять значение переменной true/false с помощью чекбокса?

Tags: javascript

```
const template = data => `
    <input type="checkbox" ${data.status ? 'checked' : ''} onclick="setStatus(${data.status = !data.status})">
`
```

Как менять data.status при каждом клике на чекбокс?

На данный момент он передает только значение на момент загрузки и не меняет его поочередно при клике и приходится перезагружать страницу, чтобы загрузить другое значение и поменять его.

Comment: навешайте обработчик

Comment: как используется данный template?

Comment: @Grundy, получаю список юзеров ajax-ом, и в success:
            `const toHTML = users.map(template); $('#users').html(toHTML); `
Убрал лишние данные из template. Дальше чекбокс по клику вызывает функцию и меняет data.status

Comment: в строку нельзя передать ссылку на объект. Поэтому нужно либо навешивать дополнительный обработчик, либо не использовать строку.

Comment: @Grundy не подскажите как обработчик правильно навешать в моем случае?

Comment: оборачиваешь в jquery и с помощью `click`: `data => $(...).click(()=> data.status = !data.status)`

Comment: @Grundy, извините, абсолютно не понял ваш ответ. Что именно оборачивать?

Comment: вместо `...` в моем комментарии должна быть та строка, которую ты сейчас собираешь

Comment: @Grundy, ну в целом я так и сделал, но из-за того что элементов много – у меня true/false меняется по несколько раз

Comment: значит ты сделал что-то не так :-)